# How to check user folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, file-permissions

I made a file on the default folder using the following code:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("data.dat",MODE_PRIVATE);
fileOutputStream.write("Hakuna Matata".getBytes());
fileOutputStream.close();
```

The file is created and stored, I can read it using `FileInputStream` and `openFileInput`.

I want to check this file using the Android Studio **Device File Explorer**, I think my file was stored in a folder inside `/data/user/0/`, but I can not see this `/user/` folder.

It seems like I need some permissions to see this folder.

Is there any way to access my file using the **Device File Explorer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think my file was stored in a folder inside /data/user/0/, but I can not see this /user/ folder.

Paths seen by apps do not necessarily match what you will see in Android Studio's Device File Explorer or in `adb shell`.

Most likely, your files can be found in `/data/data/.../files/`, where `...` is your application ID.